# SQL Server online/offline scenario

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, data-synchronization

I have build an application that have to read some MS Access data from several (+100) shop locations, and save some data on a remote MS SQL server that is at the end point of a VPN. Because the quality of connection from sites to HQ site is sometimes precarious, the customer ask me to provide an online/offline implementation with synchronization capabilities.

So I made an function that detects the reachability of the IP of SQL Server, and I execute the function in various conditions: before of relevant insert/update operations, and also on a timer basis. The timer is mainly intended for forcing in case of long time connexion drop-down to save locally in some temporary locations (and then to do bulk synchronizations when comm is more reliable, e.g. in the night)

I started from supposing that the connexion failures are somehow occasional, but I find that in reality are more than frequent.

I just wondering what can be an more reliable approach.

The most situation that I fear, is to loose connexion after I start the group of 3 inserts and 1 update (based on the global performance I estimate that with all validations to be done with some server based data, the execution time is about 2000 ms per saving). I provided a kind of commit - rollback approach, but I am not convinced that is very useful.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

L.E.

I also have to say that the online/real-time scenario is important because I have to update some information about the shop customer: if it buys something it accumulates some reward points, if he return the product (after 5 minutes or 5 days) I have to remove the points from his account. So a kind of evening/night synchronization is not very desirable regarding at this aspect.

In fact I wonder how to avoid the wrong insert/update of his points if I loose connection in the time of transaction, dealing with the fact that after 5 minutes maybe another customer buy something, and I have to deal always with the last record from the POS application (because I have to know if the customer is member or not, and if is eligible to achieve points; and in the POS app is no info about customers, is only about the sales made by the shop).

Comment: You are having frequent connection issues?  If all you shops have issues then consider the connection to you server.  Have you tried to fix the connection problems?

Comment: the connection to the server is the issue of my customer. I have to develop the app in this terms (and his terms). And he is very happy with his unstable and unreliable connection. So nothing to talk here.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a MSMQ/WCF solution with an advanced "Poison Queue" handling.  You could catch a specific exception(s) that are related to off line'ness.  Or take advantage of the re-try count.

http://blogpad-online.blogspot.com/2012/04/wcf-msmq-message-retries.html

and this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10841/Surviving-poison-messages-in-MSMQ

(Those are not end-all URL articles, just to give you a taste of that functionality)

You don't mention if the "synchronizations" must be perfectly chronological.
That is a different beast.

EDIT:

You should look at sending data as "set based" instead of one by one. (RBAR).

Take a look here:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

That article is old, but shows how you can send xml down to the sql server in an atomic mode.

The "3 inserts and 1 update" could be packaged together in xml (or json if you work on a WCF/WebApi service) and send them over as a set.

But I'm not a smart phone app expert..... On/Off Wifi is a different art.

Comment: I think that must be, because of the specificity of the system: I always have to deal with the last record of the POS, because the POS don't know if the customer is member of may application. If I have 100 sales in one hour may all are for customers from my server database, or maybe not. So the girl at the cash register have to deal with to apps: first his POS app, and after she generate an invoice, I have to process/send information from the invoice to my database, but only if she decide that the customer is member in my app.

Comment: I use a regular bulk-copy transfer when I return from offline status to online with all records that I saved in a temporary local database. But also here I don't know what it happens if I suddenly lose connexion before I finish the bulk-copy.

Comment: Then make sure its in a Transaction.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk(v=vs.80).aspx